# How to stop reading from socket when there is a certain word in buffer?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I'm doing a communication between server and client and I need to close socket when there is a word EXIT included in message. I have no idea how to do this. I tried to do it with a for loop which checks each character and compare it to E X I and T and if it finds that they are following each other it close the socket but it didn't work. I also need it to write on screen everything before the EXIT word.
My code for reading and writing on screen:

```
while(1){
    client_socket_fd = accept(socket_fd, 0, 0);
    char data[101];
    int l;
    for(i = 0; i < l; i++){
        if(data[i] == 'E' && data[i+1] == 'X' && data[i+2] == 'I' && data[i+3] == 'T'){
        x = 1;
        for(j = 0; j < i; j++){
            printf("%s", data[j]);
        }
        break;
    }
    }
        if(x == 1){
            break;
        }
    //printf("reading data from client\n");
    while(1){
        l = read(client_socket_fd, data, 100);

        if(l == 0){
            //printf("client disconnected?\n");
            bzero(data, sizeof(data));
            break;
        }
        if(l < 0){
            printf("error reading form client socket\n");
            break;
        }
        data[l] = 0;
        printf("%s ", data);
    }
    if(x == 1){
        break;
   }

close(client_socket_fd);
close(socket_fd);
```

EDIT: Added code to check for EXIT, i get segmentation fault now.

Comment: A certain word ? you could try loop over what you have read and search for a pattern of that word...
Plus I'd suggest you do the read operation until its return value is the number of character you expect. As it returns the number of characters I successfully read.

Comment: Tried to loop over but somehow it didn't do anything

Comment: You did not read anything into the 'data' buffer before checking it!

Comment: But the if detects it when there is an "EXIT" present in the message

Comment: Ok I have everything now just missing that so it prints everything before EXIT